# Projectile: How to include files of a sub directory into the project of of it's parent directory?

Tags: projectile, config

Given a project directory `my-project` which projectile correctly identifies because it is a git project.

Inside `my-project` there is a `my-module` directory. It is a git submodule and therefor projectile identifies it as a project of it's own.

But I want all files inside of `my-project/my-module` to be considered as part of `my-project`.

What is the idiomatic way to configure this?

I would like a solution in `dir-locals.el` so it does not affect other projects.

Comment: Please don't post the same question in StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and please delete the other. Thx.

Comment: You can try `counsel-fd` if your goal is to just browse subdirectories and files within `my-project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was putting this into `my-project/my-module/.dir-locals.el`:

```
((nil . ((projectile-project-root . "/p/my-project/"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

See the issues: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/712 / https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1449.

One of the options suggested there is to (edit: I've changed `projectile-project-root-files-functions` -> `projectile-project-root-functions` which it was aliased to):

```lisp
(setq projectile-project-root-functions '(projectile-root-local
                                          projectile-root-top-down
                                          projectile-root-top-down-recurring
                                          projectile-root-bottom-up))
```

Edit: I see you want this to not to affect other projects so you'd want to put this in `.dir-locals.el` in the project root.

Comment: This had no effect at all. Opening a file from the sub project and running `projectile-project-info` identifies the sub project as the project.

Comment: Have you tried updating projectile, and removing `.projectile` or `.dir-locals` vars which could be setting the project root? If you'd be open to sharing the project link, I could clone and see if I can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: I think moving the `.dir-locals.el` file you mention you have from the submodule root to the project root should also work.

Comment: I have reinstalled doom emacs configuration and it works now.